# Why is my listbox not getting populated?

Tags: c#, listbox, addition, using, streamreader

I have this code but it's not working. I've tried several different versions but nothing is working. I'm a newbie and still don't understand everything.

```
    OpenFileDialog filedialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        filedialog.ShowDialog();
        filedialog.FileOk += filedialog_FileOk;
    }

    void filedialog_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        using (StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(filedialog.FileName))
        {
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
            // the file is reached. 
            while ((line = myStream.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

I think there is a requirement for to much plain text in this editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're adding the event handler *after* the call to ShowDialog() has returned. Move it to before and it might work.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok.aspx), FileOK event occurs when Open or Save button is clicked.
You are attaching the event handler inside the click.
You might want to do it on page load or somewhere *before* the click occurs.

Eg :

```
OpenFileDialog filedialog = new OpenFileDialog();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filedialog.FileOk += filedialog_FileOk;
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filedialog.ShowDialog();        
}
void filedialog_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamReader myStream = new StreamReader(filedialog.FileName))
    {
        string line;
        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
        // the file is reached. 
        while ((line = myStream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```